# Retrieving file from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In my project I need to have ability to upload some files on server and to get it by name. I want to save them in `Google Cloud Storage` My submit form looks like this

```
<%
    UploadOptions op = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("myDefaultBucket");
%>
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload", op) %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

But after that file in `Google Cloud Storage` has some name that is different from one it was when I uploaded it (say I uploaded file `file.txt` and it's name in storage's bucket is `L2FwcGhvc3RpbmdfcHJvZC9ibG9icy9BRW5C...`).

Basically I just need to save some file `file.txt` on server and after that get it by it's name `file.txt`.

Comment: The file name is meta information and available in your `/upload` servlet by calling `BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().getFileInfos(request);`. You cannot set the file name in HTML. Think how horrible that would be if any user could overwrite your files on your drive / storage simply by providing the name of an existing file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of uploading directly to Cloud Storage, you can POST this form to your own servlet. Then you create a file name using your bucket and the name of submitted file, and save this file to Cloud Storage.

```
private final GcsService gcsService =
GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());

GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
gcsService.createOrReplace(GcsFilename(bucketName, uploadedFileName), GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a filename and folder and ... if you use a direct upload (POST) to GCS (without using the blobstore) with the [XML-API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object).

You can find my Python example code [here](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload).

[image]